# Why Ordered collection enumerates slower and how to handle it?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

Why is this code:

```
class Cord  : IComparable<Cord>
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Cordother)
    {
            return this.X.CompareTo(other.X);
    }
}


List<Cord> Cords = LoadCords();
stopwatch.Start();

foreach(var cord in Cords)
{
          // do something
}
stopwatch.Stop();
```

several times faster than this code:

```
List<Cord> Cords = LoadCords().OrderBy(r=> r.x).ToList();
stopwatch.Start();

foreach(var cord in Cords)
{
          // do something
}

stopwatch.Stop();
```

To improve performance of my application (which is handling millions of records) I need an ordered collection. I also tried using SortSet and Sort method on List item with implementing `IComparable`. Either way, the same iteration on ordered list takes a lot more time than on untouched one. Why is that and how can I get my sorted collection to iterate as efficiently as basic one?

EDIT: I measure the time of iterating only. I am aware that sorting require time for itself. The operation happening inside the loop is irrelevant.

It is literally as I comment out the line with sorting, iteration time becomes smaller. It shouldn't and in other benchmarks it doesn't, but in my current application this happens and I wonder if maybe someone can have some advice for me on this topic.

Comment: The foreach loop should not take longer in the second example. I would guess the time is lost for sorting the list.

Comment: The iteration speed is one at the same. The difference is the list preparation, and of course sorting a list is slower than not sorting it. Can't you retrieve your data sorted (from `LoadCords()`?

Comment: You say that the ordered collection enumerates slower, but the only place in your code that that actually happens is in `.ToList()`. What are you *actually* benchmarking?

Comment: Put some debug outputs like `Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);` (part of `System.Diagnostics` namespace) right before the 1st line, one right after it, and one after the loop. This should give you an idea of what's taking long. Also, try running it in `Release` mode (although unlikely, the debugger might slow it down a bit).

Comment: Sorting is an expensive operation. You might get some performance improvement if you first filter all items with `cord.x > 2` before you do the sort.

Comment: You should filter and sort data ( cord.x > 2 ...) in`LoadCords` method instead of getting all data to your application...

Comment: We can't answer accurately, because your code does provide an assumption that the database may be returning a preordered object in the example.  Which SQL is incredibly proficient at such actions. Plus, with small datasets it is possible that basic iteration can outperform LINQ, because LINQ does have to initialize all rather than per iterated value.  So for larger datasets LINQ will have vastly greater performance than basic looping / comparison.

Comment: @FlatEric that was case from the beginning. I edited the question

Comment: @IvanStoev that was case from the beginning. I edited the question

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden that was case from the beginning. I edited the question

Comment: If you want accurate performance timing you should use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch. DateTime.Now will not give accurate results.

Comment: Is Cord a value type or a reference type?

Comment: There's a good chance the time difference is in **how** you are benchmarking your code, not the code itself.

Comment: Hmm.... Interesting.  My own [quick benchmark](http://share.linqpad.net/rvcqu2.linq) is showing a discrepancy between tests, but nothing to the scale you are talking about. 10000 iterations of a 1 million element list average out to 40.336ms for the unsorted list, and 41.623ms for the sorted, per iteration. Possibly a cache coherency issue?

Comment: I ran an experiment on Leipzig 1M file (1M sentences, http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/en/download/ ), where List<Cord> is pair or length of word + word. My results are similar to yours. For non-ordered - 424 ms, 1655868 ticks, for ordrered - 878 ms, 3429800 ticks. Test code - https://dotnetfiddle.net/9B52HZ

Comment: Another thing: iteration over LoadCords().OrderBy(r => r.X).ToList() is 878, ms, over LoadCords().Where(r => r.X > 2).ToList() - 255, ms, and over LoadCords().Where(r => r.X > 2).OrderBy(r => r.X).ToList() - 755 ms...

Comment: Create a pre-sorted data file... and then compare your results... It will help out to determine if the decreased performance is due to caching issue. I guess that original data is more or less sequential in memory while for sorted data, it is jumping around in the memory so the cache memory is less useful in the second case. Also testing on different processors (for ex. a low end pentium versus best desktop i7) might allows to see if the relative performance is similar or not.

Comment: @Phil1970 seems you are right! Can you provide an answer instead of comment co we can discuss it further? I am interested how can I deal with that issue, is there someting like defragmentation for memory?

Comment: @RicoW There are not magic ways to improve the performance... You have to analyse performance, cache miss and read advanced documentation if you reach a point where you need to get optimal performance... You also have to ensure that you are using the appropriate algorithm for the job. If your data consist only in a few simple types, you might want to try using a `struct` instead and see the effect on performance on unsorted and sorted data. There are a lot of information on the web on how to optimize performance but as for most application, it is seldom needed, I cannot help you much more.

Comment: @RicoW Can you let us see what you're doing inside the loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using linq query to filter results first rather than doing a condition within loop.

```
var cords = LoadCords().Where(cord => cord.x >2);
// Now iterate via linq .ForEach/.Select to do something without if condition.
```

And moreover as other suggested using DataTime.Now wont give accurate results. Use stop Watch.

Comment: This is irrelevant and by the way using Where before slows the whole process, Stopwatch is giving the same result